# To be intent on , to intend

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs

Are both sentences grammatical? If they are, which one sounds better to your (native) ear?

Option B) sounds off to me but I can't quite put my finger on it.....

> A) Organizers have been intent on ensuring they go ahead in July [adjective form]
> B) Organizers have been intending to ensure they go ahead in July [verb form]

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatically correct but they mean different things.

> Organizers have been **intent on ensuring** they go ahead in July

They have been very focused on this goal. They are putting all their efforts toward ensuring they go ahead in July, and have not been working on much (or anything) else.

> Organizers have been **intending to ensure** they go ahead in July

It is their intent that they will ensure they go ahead in July. This is a *very* wishy-washy statement! First, it is less forceful than the first version: they are *intending*, *i.e.* it is their desire, but the statement does not imply they are necessarily doing anything toward their goal. And secondly, what are they intending to do? Not going ahead in July. No, they are only intending to *ensure* they go ahead in July. So this statement says they are twice removed from that goal, while the first statement has them only once removed.

Comment: Right. What I'm trying to do is to explore the difference between "to be intent on" and "to intend". As far as I'm aware (I may be wrong) "to intend" is more direct, but in the pp form it is more indirect, as you've pointed out.

Comment: @Gottano yes, they have quite different meanings. ["To intend"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intend#English) means "to wish/hope" while ["to be intent on"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intent#Adjective) means "to be (almost) completely focused/engrossed on."